# Backend sent unrecognized response type: u Error with Postgres 9.3 and npgsql

Tags: postgresql, npgsql

I upgraded my server yesterday from Postgres 9.1 to 9.3 and since then I've been getting an error: Backend sent unrecognized response type: u

I'm using npgsql to connect from my application to the server.

I remember that I used to get this error a while back and I haven't seen it in a while.

A full line from my log is:

```
Backend sent unrecognized response type: u
INSERT INTO stockcodes_rating (item_code,rating,price_range,user_id,timestamp_of_rating) VALUES ('10245684','5','Reasonable','10832',now())
```

My code for the procedure is:

```
Public Function InsertRating(ByVal Stockcode As String, ByVal Rating As Integer, ByVal PriceRange As String, ByVal UserId As String) As String

    Dim objDBWrite As dlNpgSQL
    objDBWrite = New dlNpgSQL("PostgreConnectionStringWrite", ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("CurrentDatabase"))

    tmpSQL = "INSERT INTO stockcodes_rating (item_code,rating,price_range,user_id,timestamp_of_rating) VALUES " & _
            "('" & Stockcode.ToUpper & "','" & Rating & "','" & PriceRange & "','" & UserId & "',now())"
    Try
        objDBWrite.ExecuteQuery(tmpSQL)
    Catch ex As Exception
        objDBWrite.CloseConnection()
        Return ex.Message
    Finally
        objDBWrite.CloseConnection()
    End Try

    Return "Success"

End Function
```

My code for the dlNpgSQLclass is:

Imports Npgsql

Public Class dlNpgSQL
    Dim _sqlConnection As NpgsqlConnection
    Dim _sqlCommand As NpgsqlCommand
    Dim _sqlDataAdapter As NpgsqlDataAdapter
    Dim _dataset As DataSet

```
Public Sub New()
    On Error GoTo ErrZ
    _sqlConnection = New NpgsqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("PostgreRemoteConnectionString").ConnectionString)

    Exit Sub

End Sub

Public Sub New(ByVal WhichConnectionString As String)
    On Error GoTo ErrZ
    _sqlConnection = New NpgsqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings(WhichConnectionString).ConnectionString)

    Exit Sub
End Sub

Public Sub New(ByVal WhichConnectionString As String, ByVal WhichDB As String)
    On Error GoTo ErrZ
    _sqlConnection = New NpgsqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings(WhichConnectionString).ConnectionString & "database=" & WhichDB & ";")

    Exit Sub
End Sub

Public Function OpenConnection() As NpgsqlConnection

    Try
        If _sqlConnection.State = ConnectionState.Closed Then
            _sqlConnection.Open()
        End If
    Catch ex As Exception
    End Try
    Return _sqlConnection
End Function

Public Sub CloseConnection()

    Try
        If _sqlConnection.State = ConnectionState.Open Then
            _sqlConnection.Close()
        End If
    Catch ex As Exception
    End Try

End Sub

Public Function GetDataSet(ByVal strQuery As String) As DataSet

    'NpgsqlEventLog.Level = LogLevel.Normal
    'NpgsqlEventLog.LogName = ("c:\npgsql.log")
    'NpgsqlEventLog.EchoMessages = True

    _dataset = New DataSet

    Try
        _sqlDataAdapter = New NpgsqlDataAdapter(strQuery, OpenConnection)
        _sqlDataAdapter.Fill(_dataset)
    Catch ex As Exception
    End Try

    Return _dataset

End Function

Public Function ReleaseDataSet(ByRef ds As DataSet) As Boolean
    Try
        ds.Clear()
        ds.Dispose()
    Catch ex As Exception
    End Try
    Return True
End Function

Public Function ExecuteQuery(ByVal strQuery As String) As String

    'NpgsqlEventLog.Level = LogLevel.Normal
    'NpgsqlEventLog.LogName = ("c:\npgsql.log")
    'NpgsqlEventLog.EchoMessages = True
    Dim RecordsReturned As String = ""

    Try
        _sqlCommand = New NpgsqlCommand(strQuery, OpenConnection)
        RecordsReturned = _sqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
    Catch ex As Exception
        Return ""
    End Try

    Return RecordsReturned

End Function

Public Function isR(ByVal tmpDs As DataSet, Optional ByVal tablename As Integer = 0) As Boolean
    Try
        If tmpDs.Tables.Count > 0 Then
            If tmpDs.Tables(0).Rows.Count > 0 Then
                isR = True
            Else
                isR = False
            End If
        End If
    Catch ex As Exception
        isR = False
    End Try
End Function
```

End Class

Comment: Forgot to mention that I'm using npgsql version 2.0.12.0

Answer (score 1):

What version of npgsql are you using? You probably need to upgrade to 2.0.14.3.

Better yet, try out the 2.1.0-beta1 which is quite stable and about to be released.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Is the 2.1 stable enough to be used on a mission critical server? I'm using 2.0.12 at the moment.

Comment: Is there a possibility that you are sharing your connection between multiple threads?

Comment: No. It's a single thread application. However the error is coming from a web service. Could that be considered multi-threaded as many instances of the service can be accessed at the same time. Although I never had this issue with postgres 9.1

Comment: This is a very known issue in 2.0.12 with PostgreSQL 9.3, upgrading should make it go away. The 2.1.0 RC is about to be released and seems production ready, but if you want to be extra safe on production servers you can switch to 2.0.14.3.

Comment: Are you getting this message as soon as you try to execute this part of the code, or does it work some time and then it starts to give you problems? Did you try to specify pooling=false in your connection string? (This way you will always get a fresh new connection).

Comment: I would estimate that I only get the error once every 100 queries. Pooling is set to false. I've replaced the DLL with 2.1 and so far I haven't received an error since I did that. (Although it is the night now and there are very few queries being processed at the moment.) I'll keep you posted. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The same thing happened to me using Npgsql 2.0.12.0 sharing the connection between threads. Making a new connection in each thread was the solution!